# Google Structured Data Testing Tool and Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

My Rich Snippets with Schema.org was working correctly for a long time already.

Now when I try a Product page at [Google's Rich Snippets testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mlmparts.com%2Fnl%2Fztechnik-windshield-vstream.html%3Fno_cache&hl=en), I get the following error:

> Incomplete microdata with schema.org.

Im not sure what I am missing, did Google make any change recently?
I read the Google's Policy hundred of times but still no luck so far.

**UPDATE**

I make a page with minimum code for my markup, still in Google's Rich Snippets testing tool: Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org.

Here my source code:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name" id="product-name">ZTechnik Windscherm VStream</span>
<img itemprop="image" id="image" src="http://www.mlmparts.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/325x325/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/v/s/vstream_4.jpg" alt="ZTechnik Windscherm VStream" title="ZTechnik Windscherm VStream" /></a>
<span itemprop="description"><p>Dit is de nieuwe norm op het gebied van design, technologie en comfort voor de touring rijder.</p></span>
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="itemReviewed" style="display:none;" content="ZTechnik Windscherm VStream" />
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" style="display:none;" content="5" />
    <span itemprop="reviewCount">1</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer">
    <meta itemprop="pricecurrency" content="EUR" />
    <span itemprop="lowPrice">€ 119,00</span>
    <span itemprop="highPrice">€ 399,00</span>
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
</div>
<div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" style="display:none;">
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/>
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span>
        <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>
    </div>
    <h3><span itemprop="name">Een prima scherm</span></h3>
    <span itemprop="reviewbody">Het scherm is goed afgewerkt en heeft een uitstekende pasvorm.</span>
    <strong><time itemprop="datepublished" datetime="202013-10-28">Posted on 28-10-2013</time> by <span itemprop="author">Ztechnik verhoogd scherm BMW  F650CS</span></strong>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please include a minimal code example that gives this error? Otherwise your question wouldn’t be useful to anyone when your page gets edited or goes 404.

Comment: Thanks. I already put the code.

Answer (score 2):

My bad, I find the issue.

```
<strong><time itemprop="datepublished" datetime="202014-02-13">Posted on 13-02-2014</time> by <span itemprop="author">Tom</span></strong>
```

The year was malformed "202014", after fixing the year to "2014", everything works fine.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try also other validator tools to fix possible problems:

- [Henri Sivonen's Validator.nu](http://validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mlmparts.com%2Fnl%2Fztechnik-windshield-vstream.html%3Fno_cache&charset=&schema=&preset=&parser=html5&nsfilter=)
- [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/)
- [w3.org validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.mlmparts.com/nl/ztechnik-windshield-vstream.html?no_cache&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services)

They are all showing *fatal errors* with specific information about them (more verbose than Google). After fixing those, test it again with Google Richsnippets testing tool.

Comment: I think it's not a problem of html validation. I make a smample page with my minimum markup and well-formatted html.